# Windows 10 cannot map network drive when it's connected in VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, openvpn, network-drive

I've got problem with mapping network drive when I'm connected to VPN(use OpenVPN).

I get this error:

```
System error 1231 has occurred.
The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
```

I'm a newbie in this, so I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me with that ?

P.S.: Don't know exactly which informations should I mention.

Comment: Are you trying to connect your mapped drive by the server name or it's IP? E.g. `\\server_name\myfolder` instead of `\\server_IP\myfolder` - this can often happen if DNS hasn't been configured through your OpenVN config

Comment: @BigChris `\\ip_address\folder`

Comment: DNS has been configured in network center

Comment: Finally solved it - I switched to Linux.